# Converting a table that has all variables of the class char to string

Tags: matlab

I have a table `t` that contains a column `year`. The following command returns

```
class t.Year 
ans =
   char
```

This is not just for the column year but for all columns in the table. 
I need to convert the table to a `cellstr` so that I can do `str2num` function on it. I am unable to convert all the columns and rows to `string` type. I also need to remove `''` from the column names when I do `table2cell`. After `table2cell` I need to convert to `cellstr` and I am unable to do so since all the values in the table(columns) are char.

Comment: `str2num` accepts `char` input, it doesn't need to be a string. But you should be using [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) anyway.

Comment: Use `class(t.Year)` to find its class. `class blah` will always return `char` since that is equivalent to calling `class('blah')`.

Comment: thanks that helps. I found that class(t.Year)  is double. I need to convert it to char. Is there anyway to do it in matlab? also I need to convert the whole table to a cellstr array.